# model object save fails with TypeError: Object of type ModelState is not JSON serializable

Tags: django-models

I have this model :

```
class TransactionAudit(models.Model):
    transaction_id: str = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, null=False, unique=False)
    # {"<field_name>" : { "new_value": obj1.value, "old_value": obj2.value}} from compare
    diff: Dict[str, Dict[str, Any]] = models.JSONField(max_length=50, null=False, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default=dict)
    requested_by: str = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    timestamp: datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
    reason: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
```

It doesn't have a primary key defined (so id is default primary BigAutoField that is generated)

When i try to save it using

```
audit = {'transaction_id': new_transaction.transaction_id,
         'diff': diff,
         'requested_by': requested_by,
         'timestamp': timezone.now(),
         'reason': reason}
TransactionAudit.objects.create(**audit)
```

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: Object of type ModelState is not JSON serializable
```

What am i doing wrong. Other models are already present in code which are successfully saving like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically any model object (lets say - `transaction` of `Type Transaction`) retrieved from DB (and if not retrieved as values dict) has a _state property. This `transaction` obj on doing `transaction.__dict__` gives a dictionary where we have _state pointing to an `ModelState` object. This `ModelState` object is what is not serializable and hence the error.